# Parse JsonArray without any root to POJO class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, webclient

I am trying to map failed response of an api to a java class. The failed response looks like this . The 200OK response is getting mapped correctly in ordersList object but in failure scenario , server is returning below json (I cannot change the response owned by 3rdParty)

```
[
    {
    "errorCode": "404",
    "errorMessage": "Data not found"
    }
]
```

Pojo

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@Builder
public class Response {

private int total;
private String errorCode;
private String errorMessage;
private String description;
private List<Order> ordersList;
private List<Error> errors;
}
```

This is how I am calling the api

```
  Response response =
      webClient
          .post()
          .uri(url, uri -> uri.queryParam(Constants.QUERY_PARAM).build())
          .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .bodyValue(request)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(Response.class)
          .block();
```

Comment: your JSON response is an array, yet you are trying to parse it to an object.

Comment: so should I convert private List<Error> errors to array?

Comment: No, you should parse your JSON to a `List<Response>`